# Storing and displaying the correct times

Tags: php, time, timezone, unix-timestamp

I have multiple people uploading log files to my website and the info that is being ingested is time stamps that look like `Wed Sep 23 13:07:27 2015` (these can't be changed as they are output by a program I have no control over) I need to convert these into UTC/GMT unix timestamps, I have access to what timezone offset they have (like `-05:00` for Central Time) I need to store the timestamps as unix timestamps because they are being displayed on the website with the website having `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` set.

This is the ingest code I currently have

```
strtotime($log["tzoffset"] . ' hours',strtotime($log["orig_time"]))
```

`tzoffset` is the Timezone offset of the user uploading the file `-05:00`

`orig_time` is the timestamp from the file `Wed Sep 23 13:07:27 2015`

This is the display code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

date('m-d-Y h:i A', $times["log_time"])
```

Comment: So is this working or not working or what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
strtotime($log["tzoffset"] . ' hours',strtotime($log["orig_time"]));
```

Where

```
$log["tzoffset"] = '-05:00';
```

For some reason `strtotime` doesn't work with the `:`. You have to send just the `-05`. If you can't change the output of your timezone offset, then I would use:

```
$tz = explode(":", $log["tzoffset"]);
strtotime($tz[0] . ' hours',strtotime($log["orig_time"]));
```